# Render looks flat compared to view port camera

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Did a landscape scene with TXA LANDSCAPE add-on in blender. The mountain looks fine in the view port but when I render the scene it looks like a pyramid or the shape it looks like. I am a beginner and I don't have much experience. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Tamil, I am not familiar with this add-on but it looks like there is difference in the Render and Viewport subdivisions settings of the Modifier(s). The first thing to try is  checking them and to make sure the Render subdivisions are equal or higher than the Viewport subdivisions.

Comment: @RumenBelev thank you so much for your answer. increasing the render subdivisions fixed the issue.

Comment: @RumenBelev please add your comment as an answer so that you can get credit for it.